# Colum X is invalid - it is not an aggregate function or group clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

tried to search for the answer already and while there are similar questions, I couldn't figure out the answer from their answers.

```
SELECT a.custid as [custid],
       a.country as [country], 
       SUM(n.qty) over (partition by a.custid) as [total qty]
FROM sales.Customers a, sales.orderdetails n
where a.country = 'USA'
GROUP BY custid, country
```

All I am trying to do is have all USA customers returned, with the total qty for each customer.

It is giving me the error.

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Column 'sales.orderdetails.qty' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Unrelated, but: read up on a proper JOIN syntax. Your usage of the ancient, outdated and fragile syntax results in a cross product because you did forget the actual join condition - something that can not happen when using the explicit `JOIN` operator

Comment: OK will do, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your script like below. You have to make the relation between the two tables by mentioning appropriate `JOIN` condition.Also remove the `OVER()` clause from the aggregate operator.

```
SELECT a.custid as [custid],a.country as [country], SUM(n.qty)  as [total qty]
FROM sales.Customers a 
  JOIN sales.orderdetails n
    ON a.custid =n.custid --give appropriate join condition
where a.country = 'USA'
GROUP BY a.custid, country
```

Comment: It is giving me "invalid collumn name" at line 5 (I added the use statement on top, so it is talking about the 4th line in your code.) sales.orderdetails does not have custid  in it, as I understand thet is the problem in the code

Comment: can you tell me how the tables Customers and orderdetails  are get linked.There should be some relation, may be through some intermediate table?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I should have mentioned. its the northwind database, one easily found online, its a test database.

Comment: I am close to achieving what I am trying to do, I want to ask how can I declare sales.orderdetails in this code without giving me an alternate error?   SELECT a.custid as [custid],a.country as [country], count(n.empid) as [numorders], t.qty * count(n.empid)
FROM sales.Customers a 
JOIN  sales.orders n
ON a.custid = n.custid
where a.country = 'USA'
GROUP BY a.custid, country

Comment: After some fiddling with your join statement I found the correct way of doing it, Thank you.